# JTextArea append performance

Tags: java, performance, swing, jtextarea

I want to print text into JTextArea, in order to do that I made simple class that handles that

```
public class Console {
    private Console() {}
    private static Console instance;
    public static Console console() {
        if(instance == null) instance = new Console();
        return instance;
    }

    private JTextArea textArea;

    void setTextArea(JTextArea area) {
        textArea = area;
    }

    public void write(String message) {
        textArea.append(message+"\n");
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
        textArea.update(textArea.getGraphics());
    }
}
```

Now, I start execution of my application and I want to log everything what is happening, for example I use

```
   public void work(Set<File> files) {
        files.forEach(f -> {
            console().write("Working on " + f.getName());
            doWork(f);
        });
    }
```

Now the problem is - performance of this can be very bad. On lower specs (or laptop running power save mode) whole console blinks with every new line, writing 50~ lines takes few seconds. Whats the cause here? How can I improve that?

Comment: That is not a JTextField. You are using a JTextArea. Be explicit when asking a question and don't mix up components.

Comment: What is `doWork(f)` doing? Is this running a long-running process? Do you need to use a background thread to help make the GUI seem more responsive?

Comment: OK, so this is a classic [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) type question

Answer (score 1):

```
textArea.update(textArea.getGraphics());
```

Don't use that statement. There is never any need to do that.

Swing components will repaint themselves automatically when a property of the component is changed, in this case when you change the text.

Comment: Allright, that works, but... I get all messages at same time - after main execution is finished. How can I achieve something like "real time" printing? So my application prints it works on file A, it does to job and goes to next file, prints again, does work again.

Comment: Your code is running on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` which means the frame can't repaint itself until all the code is finished executing. So in you have individual "jobs", then you need to use another `Thread` for each "job". One way to do this is to use a `SwingWorker`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Cuncurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the EDT and SwingWorker.